# What is the best flash webcam recorder software to use for a website?

Tags: flash, webcam, record, video-recording, yfrog

I want to imitate the webcam video record feature that yFrog has on it's site.

I know I need a flash media server or a red5 one, but I want to know what flash app do they use and what is available on the net to record videos using the users webcam.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an OS/free solution go with Red5 - the recording part is very easy to implement. Take a look at an example I posted here http://mariofalomir.com/blog/?p=101

Hope it helps.